# Typescript from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0-1 - Error TS2411

Tags: typescript

I have recently updated my TypeScript (`npm install typescript -g`)

Since, I have the following error appearing each time I compile, the compilation works but it's boring.

```
cmd.exe /D /C C:/Users/Vado/AppData/Roaming/npm/tsc.cmd --sourcemap Controller.ts -t ES5 --module commonJs
../../shared/app/lib/def/lib.d.ts(4552,5): error TS2411: Property 'length' of type 'number' is not assignable to string index type 'Object'.
../../shared/app/lib/def/lib.d.ts(4553,5): error TS2411: Property 'add' of type '(namespace?: string, urn?: string, implementationUrl?: any) => Object' is not assignable to string index type 'Object'.
../../shared/app/lib/def/lib.d.ts(4554,5): error TS2411: Property 'item' of type '(index: any) => Object' is not assignable to string index type 'Object'.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

*lib.d.ts:4551*:

```
interface MSNamespaceInfoCollection {
    length: number;
    add(namespace?: string, urn?: string, implementationUrl?: any): Object;
    item(index: any): Object;
    [index: string]: Object;
}
```

I don't understand what's wrong. How can I fix this? I haven't updated the `lib.d.ts`, it's the same file as in `1.0.0`.

Comment: Does this happen with all TypeScript files? I can't reproduce this issue with 1.1. And, where is that `lib.d.ts` from? The file did change from 1.0 to 1.1.

Comment: All TS file in the project, yes. Since I've updated TS. The `lib.d.ts` is a lib that I use inside my project. I need to reference it inside my project or I got warning about non existing classes when it compiles.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the matching `lib.d.ts` that comes with `tsc.js`. It looks like you're using some custom `lib.d.ts` from some other path (`app/lib/def` ?).

Comment: I do, it's just that I need to reference it otherwise when I compile TS cannot found some basic references. I've fixed that like a year ago so I don't remember quite exactly.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to fix this issue... I actually deleted the lib.d.ts, it appears that now TS link it automatically, I had to do it manually before.